# Mutating vuex store outside handlers issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I created a getter that takes value from state and returns different one.

```
 secondCoverageSSData: state => {
    const fs = state.secondCoverageSS;
    Object.keys(fs.data).forEach(key => {
      fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"] = `(${fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"].right -
        fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"].length}, ${
        fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"].right
      }]`;
    });
    return fs.data;
  }
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."
```

Im not sure what is causing this as Im using getter not state.

Comment: might be happening as state's data might be getting manipulated. Can you try to create a copy of the state's data (spread operator) inside your getter first and then make the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mutating nested properties of state (fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"] = ...) outside mutation handlers. an option is to detach the object from state by cloning it. For ex.

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'

 secondCoverageSSData: state => {
    const fs = cloneDeep(state.secondCoverageSS)
    Object.keys(fs.data).forEach(key => {
      fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"] = `(${fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"].right -
        fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"].length}, ${
        fs.data[key]["Risk buckets"].right
      }]`;
    });
    return fs.data;
  }
```